NextJS Web-Application, hostet via Firebase App Hosting, "redirects" sometimes to random websites
Problem Description
When accessing my Next.js application hosted on App Hosting, users (including myself) sometimes see completely random, unrelated websites instead of my application. These incidents:

Include full SEO titles and descriptions from the random sites
Appear without proper CSS loading
Occur across different networks and for different users
Last approximately 10 minutes before resolving themselves
Show completely random websites that have no relation to my application
Happen intermittently and unpredictably

Environment

Framework: Next.js
Hosting: Google App Hosting
DNS: Configured and verified

What I've Checked

DNS settings are correct
App Hosting configuration is properly set up
The issue persists across different networks and users
The problem is temporary (approximately 10-minute intervals)

Expected Behavior
My Next.js application should consistently display when accessing the URL.
Actual Behavior
Random, unrelated websites appear instead of my application, complete with their own SEO titles and descriptions, but without CSS styling.
Questions

What could cause my Next.js application to display random external websites?
Could this be related to DNS poisoning, caching issues, or routing problems?
Are there specific App Engine or Next.js configurations I should check?

Please provide any insights on potential causes and solutions for this security-concerning issue.
Additional Context
The issue is reproducible but unpredictable, affecting multiple users across different networks, suggesting it's not a local environment problem.
I have NO idea, how this is even technically possible. Sometimes I get a school from crotia, sometimes a website from a turkish news center, and so on.
The problem does not appear on my native app-hosting url.


Have you compared the Response Headers on DevTools from the expected and the "fake" site? Maybe some header like x-debug-original-host can give you a hint

Oh, I just saw you solved it in this other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79268502/firebase-app-hosting-shows-different-website thank goodness, this was awful from Google
